# truncating text in javascript excluding html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, truncate

I am using the following function to truncate text which has a `"read more"` button next to it.

```
truncateText: function (string, targetCharacterLength) {
    var length = string.length;
    if (length < targetCharacterLength) {
        return (string)
    } else {
        var shortenedString = string.slice(0, targetCharacterLength);
        shortenedString = shortenedString.slice(0,shortenedString.lastIndexOf(' ')) + '... ';
        return shortenedString
    }
}
```

So the problem I have is with `< a >` tags inside the text. If it starts just before the `"read more"` button the functionality of the button breaks.

This is what I see when I inspect element on the text where an `< a >` tag starts just before the `"..."`

```
< a... < a="" href="#" class="more" > Read More < /a...>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can solve this problem? I cannot use plugins.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep the links as links in truncated string? If it doesn't matter, you can send that string as a plain text into the function.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlsave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the Last index of `</a>` for anchor block in the input string. You can do this by using [.lastIndexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) JavaScript Api.

Try the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7d9ray3g/4/), Here i have given a text with an anchor tag in it. The code finds the end of markup body `</a>` .

It is a rough example, so i think there is a review needed for using some string other than `/a>`.

I have updated the function as below

```
function truncateText(string, targetCharacterLength) {
    var length = string.length;
    if (length < targetCharacterLength) {
      return (string)
    } else {
      var shortenedString = string.slice(0, targetCharacterLength);
      var tempshortenedString = shortenedString.slice(0, shortenedString.lastIndexOf(' '));

      var lastMarkupBegin = -1;
      var lastMarkupEnds = -1;
      try { 
        lastMarkupBegin = tempshortenedString.lastIndexOf("<a");
        lastMarkupEnds = tempshortenedString.lastIndexOf("/a>");
      } catch (err) {}
      //alert(lastMarkupEnds);
      if (lastMarkupBegin != -1) { // has an opening anchor tag
        if (lastMarkupEnds == -1) { // not having an closing tag
          tempshortenedString = tempshortenedString.slice(0, lastMarkupBegin);
          //alert(tempshortenedString);
          return tempshortenedString + '... ';
        }
      }
      return shortenedString + '... '
    }
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thank for that but what if there are multiple <a> tags? For example the first word might be wrapped in an <a> tag. I want to show the first 200 (targetCharacterLength) characters of the text before it is truncated.